# making an update query through a subquery using ROW_NUMBER()?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

**This query does not work ERROR: 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row":**

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_update =( 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER(order by column_day_job) from table_name
) WHERE column_pearson_id = 808;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**This SELECT works perfectly. I want to copy the ROW_NUMBER () values for sequence_day_job column, in the same order**

```
SELECT  column_person_id, column_day_job, sequence_day_job,
ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (PARTITION BY column_person_id
      ORDER BY column_day_job)
  FROM table_name;
```

**UPDATE 10/09/2015 (01)** - UPDATE tried to accomplish something like this, but it did not work, if a temporary table would solve my problem? It's something that seems to be relatively simple for the use of a temporary table, and cmo will be a recurring believe that use of temporary table is not so interesting.

```
 UPDATE table_name SET sequence_day_job = (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_person_id ORDER BY column_day_job)  
       FROM PC_COMENTARIO )xx
```

)WHERE column_person_id = 808;
//ERROR: 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: Though it is interesting to know what does not work, if you need help to make it work, can you state what it should do?

Comment: 'column_day_job' 'is not a physical column of the table. It is the result of ROW_NUMBER ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MERGE INTO table_name t
USING ( SELECT rowid rid, row_number() OVER (order by sequence_job_day) rn FROM table_name ) u
ON ( t.rowid = u.rid AND t.column_pearson_id = 888 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.column_update = u.rn;
```

Note -- column_update will be unique across all rows in the table.  If you just want a unique ordering within each person, you need to `PARTITION BY column_pearson_id`.  Also, then you could put the `=888` condition in the `USING` clause and take it out of the `MATCH` clause.

Comment: I used i partition by the select in the case, but as I would use the PARTITION BY in your example? where I put?

Comment: `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.column_peason_id ORDER BY sequence_job_day) rn`

Comment: I had to remove the person's identifier alias because he was in error, then worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a subquery.  Doesn't this work:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_update = column_day_job
```

UPDATE - I think you need something like this.  The syntax might be off, but I think you need you need to create a virtual table that has the row numbers you need & then pick out the correct row.  If the dates in that table are unique, then you can use those.

```
UPDATE table_name t1 SET column_update =( 
  SELECT t1.rownum
  from (select ROW_NUMBER() from table_name t2) t3
  where t3.seq_day_job = t1.seq_day_job
) WHERE column_pearson_id = 808;
```

Comment: Hi Mr Smith. I need to catch the valroes of row_number () to do the orderly way to update column

Comment: you added extra images.  I get it now.  But think the subquery is wrong.  ?You need to return one row only from that subquery.  Check my update

Comment: Thanks for the help .. But you need to use the order by. I am taking this job just to sort numerically valroes in another column.